# Your connection isn't private error for locally hosted https pages

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, localhost

I've been stuck on this for about 6 hours now and it's driving me crazy. I had this old certificate that was useless. I deleted the certificate and now, even after creating another one for the same page, I'm getting this error: [image: Invalid authority].

The expiration date matches the former certificate's expiration date. This is a snippet of my Trusted root certification authorities certificate list in descending order by date: [image: trusted root auth certs]

And here's a snippet from Personal certificate list:

[image: Personal certs]

I have no idea where is the faulty certificate coming from. The page doesn't work on chrome, edge or firefox, all of them trying to use this cert.

Comment: Please comment if you have a wild guess, I'm stuck and have no idea how to proceed

Comment: I'm an idiot - All I had to do is change the certificate in IIS